# Compiling mpeg4ip gives dereferencing type-punned pointer error

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to compile mpeg4ip on a linux box (Redhat 9) and am getting a lot of errors because it's obviously not supported anymore. This is the error I am getting:

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/rtp'
if /bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.    -DDEBUG -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -W  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wformat=2 -MT rijndael-alg-fst.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/rijndael-alg-fst.Tpo" -c -o rijndael-alg-fst.lo rijndael-alg-fst.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/rijndael-alg-fst.Tpo" ".deps/rijndael-alg-fst.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/rijndael-alg-fst.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -DDEBUG -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -W -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wformat=2 -MT rijndael-alg-fst.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/rijndael-alg-fst.Tpo -c rijndael-alg-fst.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/rijndael-alg-fst.o
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
rijndael-alg-fst.c: In function 'rijndaelEncrypt':
rijndael-alg-fst.c:126: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
rijndael-alg-fst.c:147: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
rijndael-alg-fst.c:170: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
rijndael-alg-fst.c: In function 'rijndaelDecrypt':
rijndael-alg-fst.c:274: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
rijndael-alg-fst.c:296: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
rijndael-alg-fst.c:318: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
make[5]: *** [rijndael-alg-fst.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/rtp'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/rtp'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/rtp'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The offending method (or at least one of them) is:

```
int rijndaelEncrypt(word8 a[16], word8 b[16], word8 rk[MAXROUNDS+1][4][4], int ROUNDS) {
    int r;
    word8 temp[4][4];

*((word32*)temp[0]) = *((word32*)(a   )) ^ *((word32*)rk[0][0]);
*((word32*)temp[1]) = *((word32*)(a+ 4)) ^ *((word32*)rk[0][1]);
*((word32*)temp[2]) = *((word32*)(a+ 8)) ^ *((word32*)rk[0][2]);
*((word32*)temp[3]) = *((word32*)(a+12)) ^ *((word32*)rk[0][3]);
*((word32*)(b    )) = *((word32*)T1[temp[0][0]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[1][1]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[2][2]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[3][3]]);
*((word32*)(b + 4)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[1][0]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[2][1]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[3][2]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[0][3]]);
*((word32*)(b + 8)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[2][0]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[3][1]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[0][2]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[1][3]]);
*((word32*)(b +12)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[3][0]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[0][1]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[1][2]])
                                            ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[2][3]]);
    for (r = 1; r < ROUNDS-1; r++) {
            *((word32*)temp[0]) = *((word32*)(b   )) ^ *((word32*)rk[r][0]);
            *((word32*)temp[1]) = *((word32*)(b+ 4)) ^ *((word32*)rk[r][1]);
            *((word32*)temp[2]) = *((word32*)(b+ 8)) ^ *((word32*)rk[r][2]);
            *((word32*)temp[3]) = *((word32*)(b+12)) ^ *((word32*)rk[r][3]);

            *((word32*)(b    )) = *((word32*)T1[temp[0][0]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[1][1]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[2][2]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[3][3]]);
            *((word32*)(b + 4)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[1][0]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[2][1]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[3][2]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[0][3]]);
            *((word32*)(b + 8)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[2][0]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[3][1]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[0][2]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[1][3]]);
            *((word32*)(b +12)) = *((word32*)T1[temp[3][0]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T2[temp[0][1]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T3[temp[1][2]])
                                                    ^ *((word32*)T4[temp[2][3]]);
    }
    /* last round is special */
    *((word32*)temp[0]) = *((word32*)(b   )) ^ *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS-1][0]);
    *((word32*)temp[1]) = *((word32*)(b+ 4)) ^ *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS-1][1]);
    *((word32*)temp[2]) = *((word32*)(b+ 8)) ^ *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS-1][2]);
    *((word32*)temp[3]) = *((word32*)(b+12)) ^ *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS-1][3]);
    b[ 0] = T1[temp[0][0]][1];
    b[ 1] = T1[temp[1][1]][1];
    b[ 2] = T1[temp[2][2]][1];
    b[ 3] = T1[temp[3][3]][1];
    b[ 4] = T1[temp[1][0]][1];
    b[ 5] = T1[temp[2][1]][1];
    b[ 6] = T1[temp[3][2]][1];
    b[ 7] = T1[temp[0][3]][1];
    b[ 8] = T1[temp[2][0]][1];
    b[ 9] = T1[temp[3][1]][1];
    b[10] = T1[temp[0][2]][1];
    b[11] = T1[temp[1][3]][1];
    b[12] = T1[temp[3][0]][1];
    b[13] = T1[temp[0][1]][1];
    b[14] = T1[temp[1][2]][1];
    b[15] = T1[temp[2][3]][1];
    *((word32*)(b   )) ^= *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS][0]);
    *((word32*)(b+ 4)) ^= *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS][1]);
    *((word32*)(b+ 8)) ^= *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS][2]);
    *((word32*)(b+12)) ^= *((word32*)rk[ROUNDS][3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please suggest to me how to fix this? I have found newer versions of this file online (version 3) but when I try to implement that I get more errors than you can shake a stick at. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitely try to compile a newer version. What errors do you get when doing so? As to the errors above, try using `memcpy()` or unions instead of type punning through pointerd to silence the warnings.

Comment: How do I do use unions and memcpy? I am so NOT a C or C++ programmer

Comment: When I try and add the version 3.0 of rtp it is so completely different that it just trades out the errors that Im getting for new one that I have no idea how to fix and cannot find answers on the internet. Can anyone just point out to me how to fix one of the lines above? I'm not that familiar with C++. Im more of php'er and pointers confuse the you-know-what out of me.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest source ( mpeg4ip-1.6.1 version for me) from

ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/distfiles/mpeg4ip-1.6.1.tar.gz

(comment the line 126 of include/mpeg4ip.h if error shows)

```
make and make install
```